# Python: starting and ending a while loop with time difference

Tags: python, datetime, while-loop

im trying to start and end the while loop with a time difference.
At first Im getting the current time with date time.now
in my def I want to create a time difference. This should be 10 seconds.
The function should give a False, if the seconds were expired and the current time is equal to the previous time (current time + 10s). Otherwise it should give me a True return.
After this im setting the "Zeit" variable to True, so the while loop can start.
In the while loop im starting the "fkt_Zeit", to change the "Zeit" condition at the while loop to False, after the 10 seconds expire.
So that's my plan, but its not working. The "Zeit" variable never changes to False.
Can you please help me finding my mistake?
And sorry for my bad english...

```
akt_zeit = datetime.now()
timedelta = timedelta(seconds=10)

def fkt_Zeit(akt_zeit, timedelta):
    off_time = akt_zeit + timedelta
    while(True):
        if(akt_zeit < off_time):
            return True
        else:
            return False
            
Zeit = True    

while(Zeit == True):
    Zeit = fkt_Zeit(akt_zeit, timedelta)
```

Comment: `akt_zeit` will never change and therefore `off_time` will never change and therefore `akt_zeit < off_time` will always be true.

Comment: You have to call `fkt_Zeit(datetime.now(), timedelta)` instead.

Comment: You should use profiling if you want to calculate time difference

Comment: @DeepakTripathi what do you mean with "profiling"?

Comment: you can search for this,  this way you can analyze your functions and code written in python. but i don't think you need this

Answer (score -1):

In this code

```
while(Zeit == True):
    Zeit = fkt_Zeit(akt_zeit, timedelta)
```

you call the function fkt_zeit, but notice that the time delta is computed inside this function. That means that every time you call fkt_zeit you reset the time needed for fkt_zeit to return false. That's why your function is never returning false. I'd suggest moving the off_time computation outside of the fkt_zeit function. For example:

```
def fkt_Zeit(akt_zeit, timedelta):
    while(True):
        if(akt_zeit < off_time):
            return True
        else:
            return False
            
Zeit = True     
off_time = akt_zeit + timedelta # so the off_time doesn't keep resetting

while(Zeit == True):
    Zeit = fkt_Zeit(akt_zeit, timedelta)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you checked if this makes a difference?

Comment: It does work, but the principle behind why the code was failing is more important than how exactly it was implemented.

Comment: I tried it, but "Zeit" ist still staying True